# Kivy app won't launch on android phone

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm making a simple app to (in the future) see some stuff from a webpage. At the moment it works perfectly on windows( it logs in and gives a new page).But it stopped working on my phone. It won't launch with kivy launcher. It can't be too big for it. I have no idea what is the problem. I have tried everything...
Here's my code:

```
        #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
    import kivy
    kivy.require('1.8.0')
    import webbrowser
    import urllib.request
    import re

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty 
    from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

    from kivy.lang import Builder

    Builder.load_string("""
    <Phone>:
        sm: _screen_manager
        usernameField: username
        passwordField: password
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            ScreenManager:
                size_hint: 1, .9
                id: _screen_manager
                Screen:
                    name: 'Avakuva'             

                    Label: 
                        markup: True
                        text: '[size=50]Welcome to [color=8b00c3]Pelltech app![/color][/size]'
                    FloatLayout:
                        Button:
                            text: 'Info'
                            size_hint: .2, .1
                            pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .1}
                            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'Info'  
                        Button:
                            text: 'Login' 
                            size_hint: .2, .1
                            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': .1} 
                            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'Login'
                Screen:
                    name: 'Login'
                    GridLayout:
                        rows: 3
                        cols: 2
                        padding: 200
                        spacing: 10
                        Label:
                            text: 'User name:'
                        TextInput:
                            id: username
                        Label:
                            text: 'Password:'
                        TextInput:
                            id: password
                            password: True
                        Label:
                            text:''
                        Button:
                            text:"Log in"
                            on_press: root.goToBurners(username.text, password.text)

                Screen:
                    name: 'Info'
                    GridLayout:
                        rows:2
                        cols:1
                        padding: 200
                        spacing: 10
                        Label:
                            haling: 'justify'
                            text:'This app is for pelletburner owners. For more information contact:'
                        Button:
                            text:'Pelltech'
                            on_press: root.openPage()
                    FloatLayout:
                        Button:
                            text: 'Back'
                            size_hint: .2, .1
                            pos_hint: {'x': .4, 'y': .1}
                            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'Avakuva'
                Screen:
                    name: 'Menu'
                    GridLayout:
                        rows:3
                        cols:1
                        padding:200
                        spacing: 10
                        Label:
                            markup: True
                            text: 'Menüü:'
                        Button:
                            text: 'Minu põletid'  
                            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'põletid'
                        Button: 
                            text: 'Muu'

                Screen:
                    name: 'põletid'
                    GridLayout:
                        rows:4
                        cols:1
                        padding: 200
                        spacing: 10
                        Label:
                            markup: True
                            text: 'Burner 1'

                        Label:
                            markup: True
                            text: 'Burner 2'
                        Label:
                            markup: True
                            text: 'Burner 3'
                        Button:
                            text: 'Back'
                            size: 50, 50
                            on_press: _screen_manager.current = 'Menu' 
    """)

    class Phone(FloatLayout):
        def openPage(self):
            webbrowser.open('http://www.pelltech.eu')

        def goToBurners(self, username, password):
            #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            print("1")
            params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password, 'nextPage':'/'})
            headers={'Content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Accept':'text/plain'}
            print("2")
            req = UrlRequest('http://10.1.1.116/account/login?',req_headers=headers, req_body=params, method = "POST", on_redirect = self.gotResults, on_success=self.loginSuccess, on_failure=self.connectionFail)
            timeout = 10

        def newSuccess(self, req, result):
            print("new success")
            print(req.resp_status)
            print(result.decode())
            sm=ObjectProperty(ScreenManager())
            self.sm.current = 'Menu'

        def newFail(self, req, result):
            print("new fail")
            print(req.resp_status)
            print(result.decode())

        def newRedirect(self, req, result):
            print("new redirect")
            print(req.resp_status)
        print(result.decode())

    def gotResults(self, req, result):
        print(req.resp_status)
        print('on_redirect tõi siia') 
        #print(req.resp_headers)
        headerText = str(req.resp_headers)
        cookieStart = headerText.find('sessionid')
        #cookieEnd = headerText.find('expires')-2
        cookieEnd = headerText.find('=/')+2
        cookie = headerText[cookieStart:cookieEnd]
        print(cookie)
        headers={'Cookie': cookie}
        req = UrlRequest('http://10.1.1.116/',req_headers=headers, method = "POST", on_redirect = self.newRedirect, on_success=self.newSuccess, on_failure=self.newFail)

    def loginSuccess(self, req, result):
        print(req.resp_status)
        print("on_success t6i siia")
        print (result.decode())
        content = Button(text = 'Proovi uuesti!', size = (20,20))
        popup = Popup(title= 'Login ebaõnnestus!', content = content, size_hint = (None, None), size = (400,400), auto_dismiss = False)
        content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()
        self.usernameField.text = ""
        self.passwordField.text = ""

    def connectionFail(self, req, result):
        print("on_failure t6i siia")
        print(req.resp_status)
        content = Button(text = 'Proovi uuesti!', size = (20,20))
        popup = Popup(title= 'Ühendus serveriga puudub!', content = content, size_hint = (None, None), size = (400,400), auto_dismiss = False)
        content.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Phone()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the debug instructions [in the kivy documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform), and paste the logcat output here if it doesn't make the answer clear.

Comment: Also post your buildozer.spec. You may not be including the necessary Android permissions required by your app (INTERNET)

Comment: Well..I should have mentioned that I'm writing it in sublime text and using kivy launcher app to launch my app ( which I mentioned). I will try to put up an android emulator and get the log...

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue in past and I solve by adding requirements in .spec

This requirements work for me:

```
requirements = hostpython3==3.7.8,python3==3.7.8,kivy==1.11.1, certifi,chardet, lxml, docutils, future, idna, Kivy-Garden, Pygments, requests, six, soupsieve, urllib3, deep-translator, arabic-reshaper, python-bidi, openssl, pyopenssl, numpy, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, setuptools, zope.interface, datetime
```

you have to write all modules and parent module in requirements which your app is using.

To know module which you app is using has two method:

1. run command pip freeze in current app folder in powershell
2. install all the module as below photo which help to install your application module

[image]